# Excel VBA: Create a clustered column chart that sorts based on value not series?

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, graphing

Here is my issue:  I have a user-specified number of data sets that I want to plot on a clustered column graph.  I am creating the chart in visual basic and I am adding the data sets as separate series, so that they are distinguishable by color and have different titles on the legend:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add 'all of this just adds a new chart
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
With ActiveChart
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Ordered Distribution Graph"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Item"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Total"
    .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
End With

ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Distribution Chart"

For j = 0 To UBound(chartLabels) 'here is where I handle the data based on global variables
    If IsEmpty(chartLabels(j)) Then Exit For
    Erase xval
    Erase yval
    ReDim Preserve xval(0 To 0)
    ReDim Preserve yval(0 To 0)
    xval(0) = chartData(0, j, 0)
    yval(0) = chartData(2, j, 0)

    For i = 0 To UBound(chartData, 3) - 1
        If Not IsEmpty(chartData(2, j, i + 1)) Then
            ReDim Preserve xval(0 To i + 1)
            ReDim Preserve yval(0 To i + 1)
            xval(i + 1) = chartData(0, j, i + 1)
            yval(i + 1) = chartData(2, j, i + 1)
        End If
    Next

    Call bubblesortData(j, UBound(xval)) 'separate sort function

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries 'plots each series
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j + 1).XValues = xval
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j + 1).Values = yval
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j + 1).Name = main.chartLabels(j)
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 10
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).Overlap = -10
Next

Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count).Activate
```

Currently, each set of data is sorted using the **bubblesortData(setNumber, numberOfDataPoints)** subroutine (xval and yval are global arrays):

```
Sub bubblesortLosses(b As Variant, tot As Variant)
Dim changed As Integer, temp As Variant

Do
changed = 0
    For i = 0 To tot - 1
    If Not IsEmpty(xval(i)) Then
        If yval(i) > yval(i + 1) Then
            temp = xval(i)
            xval(i) = xval(i + 1)
            xval(i + 1) = temp
            temp = yval(i)
            yval(i) = yval(i + 1)
            yval(i + 1) = temp
            changed = 1
        End If
    End If
    Next

Loop Until changed = 0
End Sub
```

This is working fine, but results in something like this:

[image: ExampleChart]

Each set is ordered due to my sort, but I would like **all** of the data to be sorted based on y-axis value.  I cannot think of a way to accomplish this while also keeping the data separated by series.  Is there a way to display x-axis values based on corresponding y-axis value and not based on series position??

Comment: Resize the array of data and fill in blank values where necessary, so that each series has the same number of data points. Probably not the easiest to implement, given Excel/VBA limitations of using Arrays.  Can you show the code for function `bubbleSortData`?

Comment: Alternatively, create it as a single series of data and apply the coloring format selectively to each data point. Again, probably not *easy* to do considering the sorting that needs to take place and ensuring they remain mapped to the right color. Using `Dictionary` or `Collection` in this case is probably better than arrays.

Comment: @DavidZemens I added the code for the sort, but yes I think you are correct in that the options you listed are probably the only ones I have to go on.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I found a combination of solutions that worked for me, mostly drawing information from this link: http://peltiertech.com/chart-with-a-dual-category-axis/

...As well as from a variety of StackOverflow posts indicating that doing this is impossible programmatically and must be done through the worksheet, which has worked for me.  I filled in worksheet cells like was done in the above link, except with visual basic.  Then, after the data was graphed, I hid the worksheet.  This works for me because the worksheets are cleared every time the user starts over with a new data set.  Here is my code:

```
Sub Distribution()
Dim runningTotal, seriesNumber, sheetName

seriesNumber = 1
runningTotal = 2

currDist = currDist + 1
sheetName = "DistData" + CStr(currDist)

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count)
ActiveSheet.Name = sheetName
ActiveSheet.Visible = True

For j = 0 To UBound(chartLabels)
    If IsEmpty(chartLabels(j)) Then Exit For
    Erase xval
    Erase yval
    ReDim Preserve xval(0 To 0)
    ReDim Preserve yval(0 To 0)
    xval(0) = chartData(0, j, 0)
    yval(0) = chartData(2, j, 0)

    For i = 0 To UBound(chartData, 3) - 1
        If Not IsEmpty(chartData(2, j, i + 1)) Then
            ReDim Preserve xval(0 To i + 1)
            ReDim Preserve yval(0 To i + 1)
            xval(i + 1) = chartData(0, j, i + 1)
            yval(i + 1) = chartData(2, j, i + 1)
        End If
    Next

    Call bubblesortLosses(j, UBound(xval))

    Sheets(sheetName).Select

    Cells(1, seriesNumber + 2) = chartLabels(j)
    Cells(runningTotal, 1) = chartLabels(j)

    For k = 0 To UBound(xval)
        Cells(runningTotal, 2) = xval(k)
        Cells(runningTotal, seriesNumber + 2) = yval(k)
        runningTotal = runningTotal + 1
    Next

    seriesNumber = seriesNumber + 1

Next

ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
With ActiveChart
    .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Ordered Distribution Graph"
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.MultiLevel = True
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Item"
    .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
    .Axes(xlValue).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Total"
    .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
End With

ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Distribution " + CStr(currDist)

ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 10
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).Overlap = 100

Sheets(sheetName).Visible = False
Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count).Activate

End Sub
```

The bubblesort subroutine is the same as was used in the question.  The final result for one of my test runs is here:

[image]

Item number is listed, but the category labels are cut out of the picture due to confidentiality.  They would read similar to "Series 1", "Series 2", and "Series 3"